# Regex to get a guid from a email reply

Tags: regex, guid

Trying to figure out the Regex pattern to match if an email contains a Guid, e.g.

> a141aa94-3bec-4b68-b562-6b05fc2bfa48-reply@site.com

The Guid could potentially be anywhere before the @, e.g.

> reply-a141aa94-3bec-4b68-b562-6b05fc2bfa48@wingertdesign.com

Answer (score 22):

I use this to find Guids

```
Regex isGuid = new Regex(@"^(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Answer (score 10):

A lazy variant would be

([0-9a-f-]{36}).*?@

It is easy to read and I bet it matches 99,99% of all cases ;) But then in 0,00001% of all cases sombody could have an email address that fits in a GUID scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming it's always going to be in standard GUID notation like that, if the following regex matches there was a GUID. You should also apply your language's method of making it case-insensitive.

```
[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}[^@]*@
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^@]*([a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12})
```

will match the any hex in the 8-4-4-4-12 format that comes before a @

Answer (score 0):

there is also one way in a single line to get GUID

```
 string findGuid = "hi Aether experiment 1481de3f-281e-9902-f98b-31e9e422431f @sdfsf 1481de3f-281e-9902-f98b-31e9e422431f"; //Initialize a new string value
 var guids = Regex.Matches(Regex.Split(findGuid, "@")[0], @"(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}")[0]; //Match all substrings in findGuid
```