# How to apply Client-side validation by calling a server-side function in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, validation, serverside-javascript

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms application.

I have a `Form` with various `TextBox`and right now I have several `asp:RequiredFieldValidator` linked to them belonging to the same `ValidationGroup`.

Now I have to apply to some `TextBox` an additional validation with related error message. 
In the specific I got to check whether the text inside the `TextBox` is a `Guid` or not. Morevoer this check has to be done on the fly, meaning that as soon as the user moves the cursor from the `TextBox` the validation has to be performed, without the need to press submit.

1. How can I call the `IsGuid(string guid)` function from Javascript?
2. How can I attach two different error messages as validation (for instance I want to be displayed a message if `TextBox.Text` has carachters not allowed and lenght < N)
3. Is it easier to implement this validation with **jQuery** or with the **ASP.NET validators**?

If somebody else has any other idea for its implementation, please feel free to propose. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ReqularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) control.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/856339/782754) a regex

```
^(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}$
```

Comment: thansk, I use the same Regex already in my server-side IsGuid function. Is there any way to use AJAX to asynchronously send the text in the TextBox to the fucntion?

Comment: You don't need to use server code. The RegularExpressionValidator control is from the same area as RequiredFieldValidator. Do you have any reason for not using it?

Comment: no but just in case I need another validation where I should implement more complex business rules, maybe with DB access. In that case I'd need a server fucntion to be called from JavaScript

Comment: For complex rules, use CustomValidator. To access server side code, you need to use AJAX. jQuery is a good tool to easy the things

Answer (score 0):

You can apply as many Validators as you need to the same control, in this case your TextBox.

In this scenario, a Custom Validator is the way to go because it enables you to do the validation with any function you develop to cover your needs. Please, have a look at this simple [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145934/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/073102-1.aspx).

**UPDATE 1**: Server Side Validation

This is how it calls the server side function in the declaration of the CustomValidator:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="custPrimeCheck"
    ControlToValidate="txtPrimeNumber"
    OnServerValidate="PrimeNumberCheck"
    ErrorMessage="Invalid Prime Number" />
```

Example of the "PrimeNumberCheck" VB function:

```
Sub PrimeNumberCheck(sender as Object, args as ServerValidateEventArgs)
Dim iPrime as Integer = Cint(args.Value), iLoop as Integer, _
    iSqrt as Integer = CInt(Math.Sqrt(iPrime))

For iLoop = 2 to iSqrt
  If iPrime mod iLoop = 0 then
    args.IsValid = False
    Exit Sub
  End If
Next

args.IsValid = True
End Sub
```

**UPDATE 2**: Client Side Validation

This is how it calls the server side function in the declaration of the CustomValidator:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="custPrimeCheck"
    ControlToValidate="txtPrimeNumber"
    ClientValidationFunction="CheckPrime"
    ErrorMessage="Invalid Prime Number" />
```

Example of the "CheckPrime" JavaScript function:

```
function CheckPrime(sender, args)
{
    var iPrime = parseInt(args.Value);
    var iSqrt = parseInt(Math.sqrt(iPrime));

    for (var iLoop=2; iLoop<=iSqrt; iLoop++)
      if (iPrime % iLoop == 0) 
      {
          args.IsValid = false;
         return;
      }

    args.IsValid = true;
}
```

Thanks to @AdrianIftode for making me aware of this.

Comment: This server side function is called.. server side. It won't be called on client. You need to create a javascript function which checks for a prime number.

Comment: @AdrianIftode I may be confused, but as far as I know this answer responds this question: How to apply Client-side validation by calling a server-side function in ASP.NET. Right?

Comment: It doesn't completely respond. You can call server side code, but not with a custom validator. Check for AJAX, WebMethods. A custom validator needs also a javascript function. That function will be able to call server side code using AJAX.

Comment: @AdrianIftode Please, have a look at the tutorial I recommended: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/073102-1.aspx since it does not concur with your argument

Comment: Well, actually it says "try entering a nonprime number, such as 6, into the TextBox - you are not alerted to the fact that the number you entered is not prime until you submit the form"

Comment: @AdrianIftode I have just updated my answer. Thank you. Regards,

Comment: @aleafonso, I read your article and your answer. You actually do not call any server-side function from the Javascript

Comment: @CiccioMiami Once you know how to call the JavaScript function, you need to know how to call your codebehind. These are separate problems. The following links might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158055/asp-net-call-webmethod-from-javascript-asyncronous, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/180355/Calling-a-code-behind-function-from-JavaScript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828803/how-to-call-code-behind-server-method-from-a-client-side-javascript-function

Comment: @CiccioMiami and if my answer was any useful at all, please upvote

Comment: @aleafonso: sorry but you just explained how to use the CustomValidator. I know already that, I want to know how to call a server function from Javascript

Comment: @CiccioMiami cool! So, create the right question for it. My most sincere apologise for any inconvenience caused