# Execute NHibernate-generated prepared statements in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, prepared-statement

Configuring NHibernate to display executed SQL does what it's supposed to, but whenever a SQL string needs to be copy-pasted into SQL Server Management Studio, we have to rearrange it dramatically in order to be compatible.

Before I dive into developing my own application that parses and rearranges this into a more ManagementStudio-friendly SQL, I'd like to reassert that this hasn't been done before - I'd hate to spend time on this and find out later.

Is there a cheap and practicable way of converting the NH-generated prepared statement into something that's executable straight away?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I posted an edit to my answer below.  This seems like it could be a decent solution if it works and if you are using log4net.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know you can do this with nhibernate profiler but this is not a free tool.  I would also be interested in a free alternative to doing this.

http://nhprof.com/

#### Edit

Looks like there is a custom appender out there for log4net that will format it such that you can actually run the sql NHibernate spits out. I saw it in the blog listed below:

http://gedgei.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/logging-nhibernate-queries-with-parameters/

Below is the code I have taken from the above blog and modified to work with Guids:

```
/// <summary>
/// This log4net appender is used for outputting NHibernate sql statements in a sql management studio friendly format.
/// This means you should be able to copy the sql output from this appender and run it directly.  Normally in the NHibernate
/// output there is parameterized sql that must be manually edited to run it.
/// </summary>
public class NHibernateSqlAppender : ForwardingAppender
{
    private const string GuidRegex = @"\b[A-F0-9]{8}(?:-[A-F0-9]{4}){3}-[A-F0-9]{12}\b";

    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        var loggingEventData = loggingEvent.GetLoggingEventData();

        if (loggingEventData.Message.Contains("@p"))
        {
            StringBuilder messageBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            string message = loggingEventData.Message;
            var queries = Regex.Split(message, @"command\s\d+:");

            foreach (var query in queries)
                messageBuilder.Append(ReplaceQueryParametersWithValues(query));

            loggingEventData.Message = messageBuilder.ToString();
        }

        base.Append(new LoggingEvent(loggingEventData));
    }

    public static string ReplaceQueryParametersWithValues(string query)
    {
        string returnQuery = Regex.Replace(query, @"@p\d+(?=[,);\s])(?!\s*=)", match =>
        {
            Regex parameterValueRegex = new Regex(string.Format(@".*{0}\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*[\[].*", match));
            return parameterValueRegex.Match(query).Groups[1].ToString();
        });

        //Place single quotes around all Guids in the sql string
        returnQuery = Regex.Replace(returnQuery, GuidRegex, "'$0'", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        int parameterListIndex = returnQuery.LastIndexOf("@p0");

        if (parameterListIndex != -1)
        {
            //Truncate the paramter list off the end since we are substituting the actual values in the regular expression above
            //The -1 also cuts off the semicolon at the end
            return returnQuery.Substring(0, parameterListIndex).Trim();
        }

        return returnQuery.Trim();
    }
}
```

Here is how you would send this output to the console:

```
<appender name="NHibernateSqlAppender" type="NHibernatePlayground.Custom.NHibernateSqlAppender, NHibernatePlayground">
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</appender>

<root>
    <appender-ref ref="NHibernateSqlAppender" />
</root>
```

### NOTE:

It appears this causes some fairly significant performance issues in a production system. I haven't found a better way to do this yet but for anyone using this beware of these performance issues

Comment: I also made one small addition to the blog post in `ReplaceQueryParametersWithValues`.  At the very end I've added the ability to put single quotes around all `Guid` values so that you can run the queries easier.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a viable Option to me!

Comment: Edited again to work with more than 10 parameters and also to truncate off all the parameters at the end.

Comment: @ColeW: Please can you include the definition of "GuidRegex"?

Comment: BTW Thanks for your answer. I used it successfully, with some tweaks.....FWIW I used this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/856339/61697

Comment: @demoncodemonkey it's been a long time but i just noticed your comment.  I've finally included the GuidRegex constant as well as the full class I use to do this.

Comment: Following up on this but it appears this causes some fairly significant performance issues in a production system.  I haven't found a better way to do this yet but for anyone using this beware of these performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this in a while but I believe using an interceptor would fit your criteria.

```
using NHibernate;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class SqlStatementInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    public override NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString OnPrepareStatement(NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString sql)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(sql.ToString());
        return sql;
    }
}
```

Credit goes to user `mindplay.dk` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5437641/1135049).

Comment: I don't need to reroute the output, I'm looking for a way to easily execute things like  `select * from foo where bar=@p0;@p0='baz'[String(20)]`